# display pandas dataframe into another tab

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am trying to display my pandas dataframe in another "Output View" tab as shown in this iamge...

https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid/blob/master/docs/images/events_api.gif

I am able to install and try the basic features of qgrid using following commands. But not able to get the exact view as shown above.

```
!pip install qgrid
!jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix qgrid
!jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix  widgetsnbextension

import qgrid
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('some.csv')

qgrid_widget = qgrid.show_grid(df, show_toolbar=True)
qgrid_widget

qgrid_widget.get_changed_df()
```

Comment: Hi, Did you mean the view of the jupyter notebook in the tab, or something else. because your code is working perfectly and doing all same as in the gif.

Comment: I am not able to create a view of the jupyter notebook in the tab. You are correct @AmitGupta

Comment: Is a new browser window okay, or do you need it to specifically do it for a new tab? check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/40855214/10953776, if you specifically need a new tab, most of it would be same, only a few commands would change and I don't want to plagarize his answer.

Comment: How do I get the "Create new view for output" option on right click as shown in the image?

Comment: Perhaps the main confusion here was jupyter v. jupyterlab.  Jupyterlab has tabs; normal jupyter notebook does not.  The image link you posted shows a jupyterlab window, but you say "jupyter notebook".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These commands should work:

## Pre-installation:

```
1. Assume you have conda environment called "myenv"
2. Assume you have jupyter-lab installed in that environment
```

## Installation of New Conda environment

```
source activate myenv
pip install qgrid
jupyter labextension install qgrid
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix qgrid
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

## Load conda environment

```
source activate myenv
jupyter-lab
create a notebook under environment myenv
```

**------------------- These are just pre installation procedures -------**
**------------------- Here is how you use qgrid in jupyter lab ----------**

```
# Lets say you have a pandas dataframe `df`
qgrid_widget = qgrid.show_grid(df.head(), show_toolbar=True)
qgrid_widget
qgrid_widget.get_changed_df()

# right click on this cell
# click Create New View for Output # it will create new tab
# You will see the new window of dataframe
```

## Confirmation

I just followed up the procedure for a new environment, and it works.
[image]

Comment: in your screen shot it is not possible to see the code to open the parallel window. would you be so kind to copy it in a comment?

Comment: @Berlines The code in in the jupyterlab/jupyter-notebook can be anything. You just load a pandas dataframe using "qgrid", then, right click the on the jupyterlab then click on "Create New View for Output". All the steps are given in the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question has a bounty on it, I can't mark it as duplicate. To show the `dataframe` in another tab, you can use a little JavaScript. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40878617/11059315) post, here is a code that will show the dataframe in another tag:

> ```py
> from IPython.display import HTML
> def View(df):
>     css = """<style>
>     table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #eee; }
>     table tr th:first-child { background-color: #eeeeee; color: #333; font-weight: bold }
>     table thead th { background-color: #eee; color: #000; }
>     tr, th, td { border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px; border-collapse: collapse;
>     padding: 3px; font-family: monospace; font-size: 10px }</style>
>     """
>     s  = '<script type="text/Javascript">'
>     s += 'var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));'
>     s += 'win.document.body.innerHTML = \'' + (df.to_html() + css).replace("\n",'\\') + '\';'
>     s += '</script>'
>     return(HTML(s+css))
> ```

Then finally you can use the function to view a dataframe like this:

> ```py
> View(my_dataframe)
> ```

This should open the the dataframe in another tab.