# How to display ipycanvas canvas object into a separated tab or panel in Jupyter-lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipycanvas

I am trying to use ipycanvas in Jupyter notebook (https://ipycanvas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is working fine. However, Jupyter notebook scroll down when you add new "section". If the canvas object is displayed above, and when you want to manipulate the canvas object in sections that are at the bottom, you cannot see the update since you need to scroll up.

I want to do something similar as to showing pandas dataframe in separate tab ([display pandas dataframe into another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55351565/display-pandas-dataframe-into-another-tab)). Is there any tools or jupyter-lab plug-in to do that?

Comment: Yes, sidecar: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks. can you put this as answer for me "tick" it for you?